# Find the simplest counterexample against exchanging limit and summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I would need a very simple counterexample to show that
$$
\lim_{M\to\infty}\sum_{t=1}^M f(t,M)
$$
may not necessarily be equal to
$$
\sum_{t=1}^\infty \lim_{M\to\infty}f(t,M)\ .
$$
The situation here is (slightly) different from the commonly asked question about interchanging limits and infinite summation, as $M$ is itself driving the upper limit of the sum. Can you exhibit a simple function $f$ which does the job? [Note that it should depend *explicitly* on $M$!]. I could only come up with an overly complicated situation, but I think I am missing something potentially very simple... Many thanks for you help.

Comment: Are you looking for an example for which both expressions are finite?

Comment: @Servaes that would be ideal, yes!

Comment: This works by using the standard sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n}1/n=1$. Just take $f(x, y) =1/y$

Comment: It's not the simplest, but one important example is the Eisenstein series $G_{2k}$. (It's dealing with exchanging two sums rather than a sum and a limit, but the principle is the same). For $2k \geq 4$, the sum invovled converges uniformly, and the sums can be freely exchanged. For $2k = 2$ it fails, and extra term pops out that ruins the behavior under the modular group. (I mention it because a lot of students think that issues like this are pedantry or simply methods that are correct but verboten because they haven't been covered in class.)

Answer (score 50):

Using [Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket),
$$
f(k,M)=[k=M]
$$
$$
%f(k,M)=\left\{\begin{array}{}
%0&\text{if }k\ne M\\
%1&\text{if }k=M
%\end{array}\right.
$$

Comment: Nice. Are the limits 1 and 0?

Comment: @EricDuminil: indeed, the limits are $1$ and $0$.

Comment: In fact, you can get any two limits $a$ and $b$ you want by this method: $f(k, M) = 0$ for $M < k$, $a$ for $M = k$, and $b$ for $M > k$.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: the sum of the limits is infinite for that unless $b=0$, is it not?

Comment: So it is; I forgot that the second quantity is not just $\lim_{M\to\infty}f(t,M)$ but is $\sum_{t=1}^\infty \lim_{M\to\infty}f(t,M)$. I'll have to think more about whether it's possible to get the sum of the limits to be non-zero.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: $f(k,M)=a2^{-k}+(b-a)[k=M]$ or something like that would work.

Answer (score 24):

Let $f(t,M) =\frac{t}{M}$, then

$\lim_{M\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{t=1}^{M} \frac{t}{M} = \infty$

as it is just the arithmetic series over M,

$\lim_{M \rightarrow \infty} \frac{M(M+1)}{2M} = \lim_{M\rightarrow \infty} \frac{M+1}{2}$

while

$\sum^\infty_{t=1} \lim_{M\rightarrow \infty} \frac{t}{M} = 0 $,

as every summand is zero for every finite $t$.

Comment: I so far like this one the most. It's easy, well-known and natural to people new in calculus.

Answer (score 17):

One example I can think of is:  $f(t,M)=\frac1M g(\frac tM)$ where $g$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, so that $$\lim_{M\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{t=0}^{M}f(t,M)=\int_0^1 g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$
but $\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\lim_{M\rightarrow \infty}f(t,M)=0$ if $g(0)\neq 0.$
For example you can choose $g(x)=x+1\text{ and }f(t,M)=\frac1M (1+\frac tM).$
EDIT: Of course that's a Riemann series, I thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @cgrudz's answer but a bit simpler. 
$$f(t,M)=1/M$$ 
Then $\lim_{M\to\infty}\sum_{t=1}^M1/M=1$ while $\sum_{t=1}^\infty\lim_{M\to\infty}1/M=0$.